# In oracle, how do I create a check constraint that checks if the time is between 10:00:00 and 21:00:00?

Tags: sql, oracle

In an Oracle database, I have a registration date column. Using SQL, I want to add a check constraint that checks the time of the date is between 10:00:00 and 21:00:00.
How can I do this?

Comment: What is the exact datatype of the column?

Comment: If you are implementing a business rule, you should do that in the app layer, not the persistence layer. By putting it in the DB, your app must catch an SQL exception to know if the time part is unacceptable, which 1) is a case of [flow control via exceptions anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) and 2) it’s an input data checking issue, so should be done up front, when receiving the data, not at the very end when you’re writing the data.

Comment: @Bohemian - What you say is fine, but it should be done *in addition to* having a constraint in the database, not "instead of" it. Why? Because many processes can modify data in the stored table (even if it's always through the application, never directly on the table). If a developer forgets to check the time-of-day in a new procedure for updating registration dates, for example, a constraint on the table will raise a red flag and force the development team to address the issue as soon as an invalid change is attempted (instead of silently allowing it).

Comment: @Bohemian - if the OP were asking about a trigger, I'd be in full agreement.  But I see nothing at all wrong with implementing this as a check constraint.

Comment: @mathguy just for context, I used to be a DBA. Then I saw the light... just because DB’s can do this stuff, doesn’t mean they should. In a real world production setting, there are no ad hoc update queries, and there are no “other processes” updating data. Actually, anyone modifying prod data manually, unless in an extreme “emergency” situation, would be fired. And I would do the firing. I would also have words with the platform engineer to do a better job of locking down update access to the DB by humans.

Comment: @EdStevens regarding triggers... See previous comment, but add: impossible to unit test, not portable, distributes the code doing the updating so more difficult to grasp/unexpected side effect situation. Although, I confess I have used triggers  very successfully once in my career. It was an operations heavy migration project where I automatically added IDs of rows loaded via load scripts and various other cobbled means into a table that was a persistent work queue to drive an indexing operation. In the general BAU case though, it’s simpler and better to not use triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the constraint should use date-time (and interval) expressions and functions as much as possible. Alas, in Oracle date arithmetic works mostly with numbers (representing "days"), so you do need to convert somewhere.

I would do it like this - easiest (in my opinion) for future developers to read and understand:

```
check (numtodsinterval(reg_date - trunc(reg_date), 'day') 
           between interval '10' hour and interval '21' hour)
```

`trunc(reg_date)` returns the date, with the time-of-day truncated to midnight. Then `reg_date - trunc(reg_date)` returns the time-of-day stored in `reg_date` - but the result is a number (expressed in days). I convert this to an interval with the `numtodsinterval`, specifying that the number represents "days". The rest should be obvious.

By the way, if you must check that the time-of-day is, for example, between 10:20 and 21:20, you can use the same approach - use `interval 10:20 hour to minute`, for example, in the `between` condition. The advantage (in readability) of writing the condition in this way becomes even clearer in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
check (to_char(datecol, 'HH24:MI') between '10:00' and '21:00'))
```

Note:  This includes `'21:00'`.  Use `>=` and `<` if you don't want it included.

Comment: Converting dates/times to strings is a code-smell (and y'know... heap allocations) - why not use `HOUR( datecol ) >= 10 AND HOUR( datecol ) <= 21` ?

Comment: @Dai . . . Does Oracle support an `HOUR()` function?

Comment: It looks like Oracle [now uses the ISO-standard `EXTRACT( hour FROM $value )` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639).

Comment: In which case: `CHECK( EXTRACT( hour FROM datecol ) >= 10 AND EXTRACT( hour FROM datecol ) <= 21 )` - also, did I ever mention how frustrated I am by the SQL language's design committee for making things unnecessarily verbose for zero benefit? ayayayayayay

Comment: @Dai . .  Oracle has supported `EXTRACT()` for a long time.  That is not what is in your comment.  And, the code in your comment is not equivalent to the OP's logic.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `check constraint` as follows:

```
(Your_date - trunc(your_date))*24 between 10 and 21
```